# Strategy for BRUTAL mode : DNA points are over!

Tags: plague-inc

I was playing Brutal mode for the first time and to spread the "bacteria" I evolved everything in transmission to first level and birds transmission to 2nd level , also all abilities to first level and cold area ability to 2nd level. Devolved each symptom (also cost me DNA points). 
Now I have my bacteria infected every person on planet but don't have any DNA points to increase its fatality.

So, **What should be the strategy for BRUTAL mode?**

Details:
Every devolve cost 4+n DNA points where n is the number of devolving till then . So , saving DNA points is very hard( given the fact disease evolve on its on).

Comment: Not to self-promote, but the easy to remember strategy I describe [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/156832/speed-run-tatics-for-plague-inc) works fine for all but mega-brutal (the infection-dependent cost increases make it not a good strategy for mega-brutal).

Comment: One suggested adjustment though: for safety, don't take Diarrhoae early in (2) - we need to start spreading by plane and ship earlier. It's also probably no high score strategy.

Comment: Patience. Seriously, if you do nothing, eventually the whole world will be infected. With this in mind, evolving 1 or 2 transmissions seems more of a privilege than a need. Addressing the mutation problems . . . select the "Creationist" gene.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gene setup:

- ATP Boost
- Aquacyte
- Sympto-Stasis
- Genetic Mimic
- Extremophile

---

1. Start in China
2. Evolve these transmissions: Water 1 and Insect 1
3. Evolve the following symptoms:

   - Nausea
   - Coughing
   - Rash
   - Cysts
   - Anaemia
   - Vomiting
   - Pneumonia
   - Sneezing
   - Sweating
   - Hyper Sensitivity
   - Abscesses
   - Haemophilia
4. Continue to evolve these transmissions: Water 2 and Insect 2
5. Evolve these symptoms if they haven't mutated yet:

   - Diarrhea
   - Pulmonary Edema
   - Skin Lesions
6. Evolve the following abilities

   - Drug Resistance 1
   - Bacterial Resilience 1, 2, and 3
   - Drug Resistance 2
   - Genetic Hardening 1 and 2
7. Back to symptoms, evolve these if they haven't mutated yet:

   - Insomnia
   - Paranoia
   - Seizures
   - Insanity
   - Paralysis
   - Coma
   - Necrosis
   - Dysentery (This one is optional, I sometimes evolve this to make infection faster. It's a bit lethal though)
8. At this point you have to wait until the whole world is infected(a pop-up appears). This shouldn't take long. Evolve some Genetic Re-Shuffles if you feel the need to do so. I use all three of mine when the cure progress reaches 40%.
9. After getting the "there's no one healthy left" pop-up, evolve every lethal symptom you possibly can. But by this point, you've probably already killed at least 80% of the population.

There might be a chance that island countries such as Greenland and Madagascar close their ports/harbors. This makes it impossible to infect these countries. This never happens when I use this strategy, but on some rare occasion that it does happen just start your game over.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were able to devolve symptoms and regaining some of the spent DNA. In that way, you can increase the fatality of your virus and kill some people. Otherwise you can wait for the clickable bubbles to pop-up and click them to gain some DNA. Another option, but rather rigorous, is start over and not spend all DNA on the transmission of the virus.

Comment: Well without upgrading the disease does not spread . Also devolving also COST DNA points and I can't retrieve any. Also waiting for 1 year I earned 7DNA points only.

Comment: Then it's probably different in brutal mode (or I remembered it wrong). I meant with the restart that you still invest points in transmission, but not as much as you did now. So that you'll end up with a slightly less contagious virus, but slightly more deadly.

Comment: I have edited the Question ..

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer per se but note that if you evolve symptoms, you are supposed to get more DNA points as the game progresses to reward you for being daunty and challenge humans in curing you. I don't know if it's still actual though.

Back when i started, i used the silent strategy often to win scenarios but soon found out that getting level1 and level2 symptoms that increase infectivity to be much better than using transmissions. Sure, transmissions are necessary but not off the start. My setup of choice is:

- Metabolic Hijack (Cause i'm lazy)
- Aerocyte (I always felt planes were more ubundant and varied in destinations compared to boats)
- Ionised Helix (To slow down cure)
- Base oxydisation (It's good to automatically mutate transmissions as transmissions help automatically mutate symptoms)
- Extremophile (Better to be accustomed to many places than just one)

Then i use the following pattern, it's not the best but it works fine for me:

1. Start in Saudi Aradia
2. Get Coughing symptom
3. Get Pneumonia symptom
4. Get air 1 transmission
5. Get Bacterial resistance 1 ability
6. Get Nausea symptom
7. Get Vommit symptom
8. Get Bacteria resistance 2 ability
9. Get Cold resistance 1 ability

   10. Get Drug resistance 1 ability

From that point on, get more abilities based on where your disease is going and take more and more infective symptoms, transmissions will mutate by themselves. Worst, to help you, take Water transmission and bird transmission but thats all...

It usually works fine!

Comment: DNA reward _seems_ to be geared to severity.

Answer (score 0):

The way I play is to to keep a low profile for as long as possible. In brutal, it's better to not get multiple transmissions(IMO), because it causes more mutations and the devolve cost first gives you back 2 DNA points, then 1, then none, then it begins to cost DNA instead of refunding it. 
Brutal Strategy (without gene modifications/cheats):
First, begin in a highly populated country(like India) that either has a lot of land neighbors or that has both an airport and seaport. Or, for a longer/harder/possibly easier game, start in Greenland, since it is one of the hardest to infect.
Keep a low profile as long as possible! Be sneaky. It's much easier to sneak around and infect most of the world before they find you. To do this, don't evolve a lot of symptoms, maybe get 1-2 transmissions/abilities.
Wait until almost all the world is infected, especially in islands like Greenland and Iceland. Then, evolve a lot of symptoms, including lethal symptoms: some good ones are Total Organ Failure and Necrosis. Evolve Genetic Reshuffle if it's needed to push the cure back.
From there, you should just be able to sit back and watch the world burn.